# When did the demand for explicit deity claim by Jesus emerge?

Tags: history, apologetics, historical-jesus, divinity

It is my opinion that the demand or challenge to find explicit deity claims by Jesus began in very recent times, possibly not until the 20th century, by groups which denied his deity.

Is there any evidence to show such a trend of time and place such as the US in the last century? If it didn't absolutely begin in the last century, then it definitely must have gained popularity recently because it seems to have become a focal point among recent Christian apologists.

Answer (score 0):

The demand for an explicit statement appears to have begun the night before the crucifixion:

> 63 But Jesus held his peace. And the high priest answered and said
> unto him, I adjure thee by the living God, that thou tell us whether
> thou be the Christ, the Son of God.
>
> 64 Jesus saith unto him, Thou hast said: nevertheless I say unto you,
> Hereafter shall ye see the Son of man sitting on the right hand of
> power, and coming in the clouds of heaven.
>
> 65 Then the high priest rent his clothes, saying, He hath spoken
> blasphemy; what further need have we of witnesses? behold, now ye have
> heard his blasphemy. (Matthew 26:63-65)

Not all Christians understand those verses in the same way (this of course could be said of most verses).

By comparison to John 10:33, and in light of the Sanhedrin's reaction in Matthew 26, I see that the Jews understood Jesus to be proclaiming His Deity, and the legitimacy of that claim was already being explicitly challenged at this early date.

Various forms of this question have been asked ever since.

Comment: Don't post if u don't have an answer

Comment: @Michael16 I did offer an answer, though it may not be the answer you were seeking. I don't see that this question began being asked recently.

Comment: If you are taking this tack, @HoldToTheRod , it would be good to add Matthew 21:23-27, which begins with their question:  “By what authority are you doing these things, and who gave you this authority?” which question Jesus refuses to answer for clever reasons.